# multiplying each element in a list in a way that- each element multiply with next and stores the value in a table

Tags: python-3.x

| N | l1 | l2 | l3 | l4 | l5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| l1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| l2 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 | 10 |
| l3 | 3 | 6 | 9 | 12 | 15 |
| l4 | 4 | 8 | 12 | 16 | 20 |
| l5 | 5 | 10 | 15 | 20 | 25 |

this needs to be the output of input list:(input list: l=[1,2,3,4,5])
I want to also publish the output grid in a csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension.

```py
import csv

l = [1,2,3,4,5]
table = [[a*b for b in l] for a in l]
with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(table)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I also want to  append the table in CSV like the output (showed in top), do you have any solution for that also?

Comment: @mdmarufi I've updated my answer.

Comment: @mdmarufi No problem.